# REST-Apache CXF-Schema validation

Tags: apache, validation, rest, schema, cxf

I am using RESTful Webservice using Apache CXF (blended with spring).
I am exposing two services in my WADL.

For every request to my Webservice,I need to validate request to a particular schema.One of my exposed service use a specific schema and other service complies to other specific schema.

Can you help me?

Comment: Lets say I have two services exposed.1.)public String getName(Employee obj) and 2.)public String getCompanyName(Company obj)....Both are two independant services exposed in the same wadl(REST webservice exposed).My first service ie.,public String getName(Employee obj) has a JAXB class 'Employee' and the incoming request xml has be validated against a particular schema.Similarly,my second service uses JAXB class 'College' and the incoming request xml has be validated against a particular schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of ways to do what you need. One way is using `jaxrs:schemaLocations` element:

```
<beans>
    <jaxrs:server address="/" serviceClass="com.something.ServiceClass">
        <jaxrs:schemaLocations>
            <jaxrs:schemaLocation>classpath:/schemas/a.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
            <jaxrs:schemaLocation>classpath:/schemas/b.xsd</jaxrs:schemaLocation>
        </jaxrs:schemaLocations>
    </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

For more information and examples please see this [link](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Schemavalidation).

Comment: Thanks.   Lets say I have two services exposed.1.)public String getName(Employee obj) and 2.)public String getCompanyName(Company obj)....Both are two independant services exposed in the same wadl(REST webservice exposed).My first service ie.,public String getName(Employee obj) has a JAXB class 'Employee' and the incoming request xml has be validated against a particular schema.Similarly,my second service uses JAXB class 'College' and the incoming request xml has be validated against a particular schema.How is it possible to include a specific schema for a specific service in cxf.xml?....

Comment: Basically,my usecase should be 'validate incoming request message against a schema(assuming everything would be xml only)' and 'validate outgoing response message against a schema'...atleast tell your tips to 'validate incoming message against a specific schema'....thanks in advance...